# Options to fix " incompatible pointer types passing"

Tags: c

```
typedef struct {
    int field;
} descriptor_t;

void function(descriptor_t (* descriptor_t)[], int descriptor_count);


descriptor_t g_descriptors[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} };   //

function(g_descriptors, sizeof(g_descriptors) / sizeof(g_descriptors[0]));
```

I have a function that takes an array of descriptors as parameter.

When I call it like above I get "incompatible pointer types passing" warning.

I would like to get rid of this warning, suggestions welcome.

Also I would like to understand why this warning, what could possible go wrong if I pass and array of fixed size to parameter of array unspecified size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration

```
void function(descriptor_t (* descriptor_t)[], int descriptor_count);
```

expect the first argument to be *a pointer to an array of descriptor_t*. To convert an array to a pointer to array just use address-of operator `&`.

```
function(&g_descriptors, sizeof(g_descriptors) / sizeof(g_descriptors[0]));
         ^
         here
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument `descriptor_t (* descriptor_t)[]` is a pointer to an array of `descriptor_t`.

Arrays in expressions like `g_descriptors` are automatically converted to a pointer to its first element (some exceptions exist, passing to `sizeof` is one of the exceptions), so you can simply use a pointer `descriptor_t* array` or an array (automatically converted to pointer in arguments) `descriptor_t array[]` as the argument.

Comment: True and thanks, but I want to keep the  pointer to array of descriptors as I think it better reflects the intent.